# Clone div on click

Tags: jquery, html

Would like to copy the text of a div to go to a textbox and add at the beginning of the text (Start) and end (final) also has forums citing a text in jquery this function .clone () but not as used to do that

```
<div id='copy'>Text and more text</div>
<button id='copy_text'>Click </button>

 <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jquery clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method creates new DOM elements - ie it copies the `div`, not the content of the div.

You can use [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text value, a simplified example:

```
$("#copy_text").click(function() {
    var txt = $("#copy").text();
    $("#content").text(txt);
});
```

To add your "start/final" text, just use `+`

```
$("#copy_text").click(function() {
    var txt = $("#copy").text();
    $("#content").text("Start" + txt + "final");
});
```

Update: While .text() can be used for setting textarea text, you might prefer to use .val():

```
$("#content").val(txt)
```

as it's clearer that your setting the content of the textarea, not changing the DOM.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4ut5tmd/

Comment: What's ckeditor?  This was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you need help with ckeditor specifically, you should ask a new question - this question was regarding `textarea` which ckeditor does not use (it uses iframes - so should use the ckeditor api, not jquery).  Link new question here.

Comment: np - try the `.val()` version rather than `.text()`

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery  - scroll down to "The .val() Method"

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#copy_text").click(function(e) {
   $("#content").text( "start" + $("#copy").text() + "final" );
});
```

You have to use JQuery `text` function (or `html` - depends on what you would like to achieve with your code) to set/get the content of HTML tag.